# Evenly distributing related records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with over 100k mailboxes and users with permissions.

```
+---------+---------+
| Mailbox | Trustee |
+---------+---------+
| smb1    | mbx1    |
| smb2    | mbx1    |
| smb2    | mbx2    |
| smb2    | mbx3    |
| smb3    | mbx4    |
| smb3    | mbx5    |
| mbx1    | mbx6    |
| mbx7    | mbx4    |
| smb4    | mbx8    |
| smb4    | mbx9    |
| mbx8    | mbx10   |
+---------+---------+
```

Need to group Trustee and mailboxes they have access to in Mailbox column. e.g. mbx1, mbx2, and mbx 3 are related by access to smb2, so they go in bucket 1. mbx going into bucket 1 means smb1 also goes into bucket 1 as mbx 1 is a Trustee on that. Then further down because mbx6 has relation to mbx1 it also goes into bucket 1. Hope the others make sense. So note Trustee's can have access so smb (shared Mailboxes) or mbx (mailboxes)

The table I'm selecting from just has Mailbox and Trustee and I want to write into a temp table below.

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| Mailbox | Trustee | Bucket |
+---------+---------+--------+
| smb1    | mbx1    |      1 |
| smb2    | mbx1    |      1 |
| smb2    | mbx2    |      1 |
| smb2    | mbx3    |      1 |
| smb3    | mbx4    |      2 |
| smb3    | mbx5    |      2 |
| mbx1    | mbx6    |      1 |
| mbx7    | mbx4    |      2 |
| smb4    | mbx8    |      3 |
| smb4    | mbx9    |      3 |
| mbx8    | mbx10   |      3 |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

I then want to put the bucket counts together to make evenly groups. Idea being I can say e.g. max count 100, so create groups of buckets that count up to around 100 users.

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Groups  | Buckets | Count |
+---------+---------+-------+
|       1 |       1 |     5 |
|       2 |     2,3 |     6 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

EDIT:
I've gotten this far where I can pass in a mailbox and get all the trustees and then the other mailboxes those trustees have access to.

```
DECLARE @int int = 1;
WITH Buckets_CTE
    (Trustee)
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Trustee
    FROM EXOPerms
        WHERE Mailbox = 'smb1'
)
SELECT DISTINCT Mailbox,Trustee
    FROM EXOPerms
    Where Trustee IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Trustee
    FROM Buckets_CTE)
    ORDER BY Trustee
```

The DECLARE Int at the top is redundant at the moment just got that there to see if I can implement the bucket feature.

Comment: So what is your question exact ? Do you want to query the upper table so you get the result in the lower table ? If so, what is the logic ?

Comment: No see the last line of my first section the table I'm selecting from has just the mailbox and Trustee. So I'm trying to write a CTE now that produces the first table. I.e. mbx1, mbx2 and mbx3 are related by having access to Mailbox smb1 so they go in bucket 1. Then the second part of the query will read the CTE, Count the members of each bucket and try evenly distribute them into groups around the same size. BTW I'm trying CTE because that's just what I know if there's a better way I'm all ears.

Comment: Well I would edit your question and explain as best as you can what you want to achieve, and it would help a lot to see sample data from where the first table can be produced

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that was a little confusing. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: So you need help with the generating the second table or third table ? For the third table, how did the `5` under `Buckets` comes about ?

Comment: Sorry I'm even confusing myself here. So I'm trying to produce both tables. I've only got the first and am trying to produce the second and the third. The second table groups the users into buckets of people who are all related by being trustees on mailboxes. Then the second count the users in each bucket and tries to make evenly sized Groups (in this case 5 users in bucket 1 and 6 in Buckets 2 and 3 make two evenly as possible sized groups). Sorry, I confused things by the last table having Bucket 5 as group 1. It should have been bucket 1 as Group 1.

Comment: To be honest I'm struggling I've only been playing with SQL over a month and might have bitten off more than I can chew on this one. I've added an edit where if I pass in a mailbox it returns all the Trustees and then other mailboxes those trustees have access to. The bucket feature might be a bit much. Can start counting up and maybe doing some of this manually.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the "buckets" concept sounds sorta like building a parent/child tree...

Comment: Not really parent/child,  It is to group those rows with related mailbox into one group under one Bucket ID. Looks like you can't achieve it with a set-based solution. A while loop might be unavoidable.

Comment: I'm actually getting somewhere. Basically putting a DISTINCT list of all Trustees into temp table then iterating through that with a while loop. Each loop pass says put that trustee, all its mailboxes, and then all trustees in the same bucket and put into another temp table with Mailboxes, Trustee, BucketName. Then the next loop get's the next Trustee from the first table and ignores it if it's in the second table. I'm getting there but have only been at SQL for a few weeks so getting the hang of it. It might be time to bring back lunch time drinking at this point.

Comment: @Squirrel - Yeah, you're right.  Looping, ugh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a while loop solution. It just iterate through every row and update the Bucket.

`ID` is added for looping through the data row by row

To check if a mailbox/trustee exists in another row, check for `i.Mailbox in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee)` :

```
from @mailbox i
     inner join @mailbox m  
     on  i.ID   <> m.ID   -- don't compare the same row
     and (
            i.Mailbox   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
         or i.Trustee   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
         )
```

Note that when update the Bucket, it compare with current Bucket and only takes the lower value. This is to resolve case like below where the relationship between earlier rows are not known until later rows.

```
ID  MailBox  Trustee 
1   a        b      
2   c        d
3   e        f
4   c        f
```

ID 1, 2, 3 is assign separate Bucket when process sequentially. Only when process ID 4, that it links ID 2 and 3 together

---

Complete query

```
declare @mailbox table
(
    ID      int        identity,
    Mailbox varchar(5),
    Trustee varchar(5),
    Bucket  int
)

insert into @mailbox (Mailbox, Trustee) values
( 'smb1',    'mbx1' ),
( 'smb2',    'mbx1' ),
( 'smb2',    'mbx2' ),
( 'smb2',    'mbx3' ),
( 'smb3',    'mbx4' ),
( 'smb3',    'mbx5' ),
( 'mbx1',    'mbx6' ),
( 'mbx7',    'mbx4' ),
( 'smb4',    'mbx8' ),
( 'smb4',    'mbx9' ),
( 'mbx8',    'mbx10');

declare @ID     int,
        @Bucket int = 1    -- start from 1

-- get the minimum ID for start
select  @ID = min(ID) from @mailbox where Bucket is null

while   exists 
        (
            select  *
            from    @mailbox
            where   ID >= @ID
        )
begin
        -- if the mailbox is found in other row with Bucket value
        -- (Bucket is not null)
        if  exists
        (
            select  *
            from    @mailbox i
                    inner join @mailbox m   
                    on  i.ID    <> m.ID
                    and (
                            i.Mailbox   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        or  i.Trustee   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        )
            where   i.ID    = @ID
            and     m.Bucket    is not null
        )
        begin
            -- Update Bucket from other row
            update  i
            set     Bucket  = case  when i.Bucket is null
                                    or   i.Bucket > m.Bucket
                                    then m.Bucket
                                    else i.Bucket
                                    end
            from    @mailbox i
                    inner join @mailbox m   
                    on  i.ID    <> m.ID
                    and (
                            i.Mailbox   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        or  i.Trustee   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        )
            where   i.ID    = @ID
            and     m.Bucket    is not null

            -- Update other rows that might linked to current ID
            update  m
            set     Bucket  = case  when    i.Bucket > m.Bucket
                                    then    m.Bucket
                                    else    i.Bucket
                                    end
            from    @mailbox i
                    inner join @mailbox m   
                    on  i.ID    <> m.ID
                    and (
                            i.Mailbox   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        or  i.Trustee   in (m.Mailbox, m.Trustee) 
                        )
            where   i.ID        = @ID
    end
    else
    begin
        -- no other row found with same mailbox. 
        -- Assign Bucket from @Bucket, increment @Bucket
        update  m
        set     Bucket  = @Bucket
        from    @mailbox m
        where   m.ID    = @ID;

        select  @Bucket = @Bucket + 1;
    end

    -- Get next ID
    select  @ID = min(ID) from @mailbox where ID > @ID;
end

select  *
from    @mailbox
order by ID
```

Comment: This is great thanks I was flip-flopping data between two temp tables and a CTE and tearing my hear out. The above works on over 113k mailboxes and seriously accelerated my learning. I've been spending some time working out how it works. Thanks!!

Comment: Edited the answer with explanation & comments. Please accept if it resolved your question

Comment: Note : this does not address the Group - Bucket - Count issue. You need to explain the logic for grouping.

Comment: Ahh thanks I didn't realise the 'resolve' tick was there. That has answered my question thanks so much for your help. Once you got me that far the bucket counting issue is pretty easy. Thanks again!